# in angular 15 how the main.server.ts should look like if I'm using the standalone structure

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

in angular 15.2 there is automated script to migrate your application to the standalone structure, it's documented here https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/core/schematics/ng-generate/standalone-migration/README.md

but running it doesn't actually migrate the `main.server.ts` or the `app.server.module.ts` files

while replacing `AppModule` with `AppComponent` in the imports make the application compile but fails on the runtime for the missing providers

e.g.

```
NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options
```

for missing `provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),`

even if I copied all of these providers to the AppServerModule I still get

```
 error NG6009: The `AppComponent` class is a standalone component, which can not be used in the `@NgModule.bootstrap` array. Use the `bootstrapApplication` function for bootstrap instead.
```

and there can't be a path forward

Answer (score -1):

You need to call `bootstrapApplication`:

Which could look like:

```
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';
  const document = readFileSync(join(distFolder, 'index.html'), 'utf-8').toString();

  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    appId: 'my-app',
    bootstrap: AppComponent,
    document,
    providers: [
       ....
    ],
  }));
```

Comment: but the `ngExpressEngine` in the server.ts file expect a Module, but `bootstrapApplication` return `Promise<ApplicationRef>`

Comment: see my edit, `ngExpressEngine` supports bootstraping components.

Comment: it gave me this error `Error: ASSERTION ERROR: Type passed in is not NgModuleType, it does not have 'ɵmod' property.`